# How to detect if fuse has blown?

Tags: microcontroller, fuses

I want to detect with a microcontroller if a fuse has blown. The circuit with the fuse is 12V when on (it is not always on, so I need to distinguish between a blown fuse and the circuit not running).
The microcontroller can only handle max. 3.3V.

I thought about using two optocouplers like this:
[image]

Is there a better solution you would use?

Comment: Nvm. I presume `3.3V-` is essentially the ground (0V) for the MCU? And that `12V-` is the ground for the +12V supply?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, could've used a better syntax for that

Comment: measure the voltage across the fuse

Comment: I think the preferred method is to use a raspberry pi, and a camera and image the fuse, and upload to a cloud AI platform for recognition. Cost Down: Put  both fuses where a single camera can see them

Answer (score 6):

If you can live with a bit of leakage through a blown fuse, **and** there is always a reasonably low value load, put one optoisolator LED across the fuse (with a resistor in series, of course, and an inverse diode across the LED wouldn't hurt).

Otherwise you could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ddsB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You need a way to differentiate between 3 current levels:

- 0 when +12 is faulty
- I/10 when fuse is blown
- I when fuse is OK

eg use two different pullup resistors, or use an ADC input

The key design issue is that there has to be a large ratio between the two currents as you have to allow for variation in +12V, Opto Current Transfer ratio from unit to unit, and over temperature, and port pin threshold.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKOaDA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course this is assuming you need isolation. If they have a common ground then its trivial...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgj86ym.png)</sup>